# each holding strange and new thoughts

Tags: grammar, meaning

Am I right if I understand 'each holding strange and new thoughts' as 'each was strange and each have new thoughts' or maybe 'each have strange thoughts and new thoughts? Also could you explain gramma of this phrase.

> When Meg and Charles Wallace returned to the house, silently, each
>   **holding strange and new thoughts**, evening was moving in with the wind.
>   The twins were waiting for them, and wanted Charles Wallace to go out
>   in the last of the light to play catch.

A Wind in the Door by Madeleine L’Engle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you want the grammar explained, but the correct interpretation is that the the thoughts they each held were strange and new.